# Using Wordpress as an API

Tags: buddypress, performance, api, bbpress, wp-api

I'm considering using the new WP API to power a mobile app.

I also want to have a web frontend with a restricted membership area, BuddyPress as well as bbPress installed.

I'm wondering though if this will be a problem if one install is handling all this functionality? Along with whatever other plugins, caching, SEO, analytics etc it all seems like it could slow things down pretty quickly or pose problems when it comes to scaling.

Is it even possible to break these 'apps' up and have say the WP-API for the mobile app, a separate install for bbPress and BuddyPress?

I know this is still very new as WP-API isn't fully integrated with the core yet so interested to see how people are expecting to use WP for apps and concerns on scaling.

Thanks